# pytest.mark.parametrize a copy of a test case without altering the original

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, parametrized-testing

## Background

We have a big suite of reusable test cases which we run in different environments. For our suite with test case ...

```
@pytest.mark.system_a
@pytest.mark.system_b
# ...
@pytest.mark.system_z
test_one_thing_for_current_system():
   assert stuff()
```

... we execute `pytest -m system_a` on system A, `pytest -m system_b` on system B, and so on.

## Goal

We want to parametrize multiple test case for one system only, but **neither** want to copy-paste those test cases, **nor** generate the parametrization dynamically based on the command line argument `pytest -m`.

## Our Attempt

### Copy And Mark

Instead of copy-pasting the test case, we assign the existing function object to a variable. For ...

```
class TestBase:
    @pytest.mark.system_a
    def test_reusable_thing(self):
        assert stuff()

class TestReuse:
    test_to_be_altered = pytest.mark.system_z(TestBase.test_reusable_thing)
```

... `pytest --collect-only` shows two test cases

```
 TestBase.test_reusable_thing
 TestReuse.test_to_be_altered
```

However, `pytest.mark` on one of the cases also affects the other one. Therefore, both cases are marked as `system_a` *and* `system_z`.

Using `copy.deepcopy(TestBase.test_reusable_thing)` and changing `__name__` of the copy, before adding `mark` does not help.

### Copy And Parametrize

Above example is only used for illustration, as it does not actually alter the test case. For our usecase we tried something like ...

```
class TestBase:
    @pytest.fixture
    def thing(self):
        return 1
    
    @pytest.mark.system_a
    # ...
    @pytest.mark.system_y
    def test_reusable_thing(self, thing, lots, of, other, fixtures):
        # lots of code
        assert stuff() == thing

copy_of_test = copy.deepcopy(TestBase.test_reusable_thing)
copy_of_test.__name__ = "test_altered"

class TestReuse:
    test_altered = pytest.mark.system_z(
        pytest.mark.parametrize("thing", [1, 2, 3])(copy_of_test)
    )
```

Because of aforementioned problem, this parametrizes `test_reusable_thing` for *all* systems while we only wanted to parametrize the copy for `system_z`.

## Question

How can we parametrize `test_reusable_thing` for `system_z` ...

- without changing the implementation of `test_reusable_thing`,
- and without changing the implementation of fixture `thing`,
- and without copy-pasting the implementation of `test_reusable_thing`
- and without manually creating a wrapper function `def test_altered` for which we have to copy-paste requested fixtures only to pass them to `TestBase().test_reusable_thing(thing, lots, of, other, fixtures)`.

Somehow pytest has to link the copy to the original. If we know how (e.g. based on a variable like `__name__`) we could break the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can defer the parametrization to the [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests) hookimpl. You can use that to add your custom logic for implicit populating of test parameters, e.g.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # test has `my_arg` in parameters
    if 'my_arg' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        marker_for_system_z = metafunc.definition.get_closest_marker('system_z')
        # test was marked with `@pytest.mark.system_z`
        if marker_for_system_z is not None:
            values_for_system_z = some_data.get('z')
            metafunc.parametrize('my_arg', values_for_system_z)
```

A demo example to pass the marker name to `test_reusable_thing` via a `system` arg:

```
import pytest


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'system' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        args = [marker.name for marker in metafunc.definition.iter_markers()]
        metafunc.parametrize('system', args)


class Tests:

    @pytest.fixture
    def thing(self):
        return 1

    @pytest.mark.system_a
    @pytest.mark.system_b
    @pytest.mark.system_c
    @pytest.mark.system_z
    def test_reusable_thing(self, thing, system):
        assert system.startswith('system_')
```

Running this will yield four tests in total:

```
test_spam.py::Tests::test_reusable_thing[system_z] PASSED
test_spam.py::Tests::test_reusable_thing[system_c] PASSED
test_spam.py::Tests::test_reusable_thing[system_b] PASSED
test_spam.py::Tests::test_reusable_thing[system_a] PASSED
```

Comment: Thank you. `pytest_generate_tests` looks like a viable solution. The official docs also have some further explanations and examples (see [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) and [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html)). I'll look into it, if a simple copy (similar to my attempt) is not possible.